# MAPI_E_INVALID_ENTRYID when getting contact from Outlook via Redemption

Tags: c#, interop, outlook-redemption

I'd like to retrieve a contact with a known EntryID in a specific folder from outlook/exchange using Redemption.

The following code calls GetMessageFromID on an RDOSession object. I only want contacts from the standard Contacts folder, so I use the second argument to limit the search space.

```
RDOFolder folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
RDOContactItem i = Session.GetMessageFromID(syncRow.SyncId, folder.EntryID, null) as RDOContactItem;
```

Whenever I do this redemption throws a COM exception: `Error in IMAPISession.OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_INVALID_ENTRYID`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetMessageFromID takes 2 entry ids as parameters (1 required, 1 optional) - the message entry id and the store entry id.
It looks like you are passing a *folder* entry id instead of a store entry id.

Comment: Ah... Is there a way to limit it to folders in a store? Currently I'm just checking where the RDOContactItem lives after I've got it.

Comment: You can use RDOContactItem.Parent to retrieve the parent folder(RDOFolder). You can then use RDOSession.CompareEntryIDs to compare the folder entry id with the entry id of another folder.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was comparing them with ==. Fixed that now.